# Words' order in sentences

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anyone please tell me, if I change words' order, then will it change meaning of sentences?

you can share **me with details** mentioned in David’s e-mail  and later we can consolidate and send to David.

Or

you can share **details with me** which is mentioned in David’s e-mail and later we can consolidate and send to David.

Thanks

Comment: you require the definite article before 'details'. Don't bother much, both are okay and convey the meaning. It's a matter of style.

Comment: Okay.. That I know, but I was thinking about order of "details with me"

Comment: I answered that too! You share some joy with me....

Comment: Ask yourself a question: what is the object of verb "share" in each of these sentences? Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't say:

> you can share *me* with details...

because this is saying you are sharing *me* (the direct object in this phrase). The "with" phrase is the indirect object. If you change it you will change the meaning.
So you have to go with:

> you can share (the) *details* with me...

since it is the *details* you are sharing.

As for the full phrase, I would replace *which are* (since we are referring to details) with *as*:

> You can share (the) details with me *as* mentioned in David’s e-mail, and later we can consolidate and send (them) to David.

Comment: Thank you...That was my understanding but i though of understanding in depth, so if we change words’ order then what it would be conveyed.